# SQL st.executeUpdate error

Tags: java, sql

This is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.Console;


class SynchList {
    ArrayList<PrintStream> it;

    SynchList() {
        it = new ArrayList<PrintStream>();
    }

    synchronized PrintStream get(int i) {
        return it.get(i);
    }

    synchronized void add(PrintStream o) {
        it.add(o);
    }

    synchronized int size() {
        return it.size();
    }

    synchronized void remove(PrintStream o) {
        it.remove(o);
    }
}


class StringBroadcaster {
    static SynchList Outputs = new SynchList();
    static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String message;
        //Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //Database password
        Console cons;
        char[] passwd;
        String pass = "";

        if ((cons = System.console()) != null &&
                (passwd = cons.readPassword("%s", "Password:")) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < passwd.length; i++) pass += passwd[i];
        }
        //Open a connection
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://igor.gold.ac.uk/ma203mk", "ma203mk", pass);
        //Execute a query to create a statement with required arguments
        Statement st = connect.createStatement();

        int resultSet = st.executeUpdate(SQLquery);
        //Execute a query

        SQLquery = "INSERT INTO one (Port,Name,Message) VALUES('a','hello','hii')";
        VALUES(1, 'hello', 'muhsina') ");


        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(port);
        Transaction k;
        while (true) {
            k = new Transaction(Outputs.size(), s.accept(), Outputs);
            k.start();
            System.out.println("Client Joined");
        }//wait for client to connect
    }
}//End of Main



class Transaction extends Thread {
    SynchList outputs;
    public int n;
    Socket t;
    InputStream b;
    OutputStream p;
    PrintStream pp;
    public String name;

    public Transaction(int i, Socket s, SynchList v) throws Exception {
        outputs = v;
        n = i;
        t = s;
        b = t.getInputStream();
        p = t.getOutputStream();
        pp = new PrintStream(p);
        outputs.add(pp);
    }

    public void run() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(b);
        name = s.next();
        int c;
        try {
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String it = s.nextLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < outputs.size(); j++) {

                    {
                        (outputs.get(j)).println(name + ": " + it);

                        (outputs.get(j)).flush();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(name + ": " + it);

            }
            System.out.print("Client " + n + " " + name + " left the conversation");
            outputs.remove(pp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            outputs.remove(pp);
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I keep getting this error for the following code, can anyone help?

```
G:\StringBroadcaster.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    int resultSet = st.executeUpdate(SQLquery);
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable SQLquery
  location: class StringBroadcaster

G:\StringBroadcaster.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
    SQLquery = "INSERT INTO one (Port,Name,Message) VALUES('a','hello','muhsina')";
    ^
  symbol:   variable SQLquery
  location: class StringBroadcaster
2 errors
```

Tool completed with exit code 1)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have executed the line

`int resultSet = st.executeUpdate(SQLquery);`

before define the value of variable `SQLquery`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared a type for your `SQLQuery` variable (also variables conventionally start with a lowercase letter to distinguish them from class names).  So the line below `// Execute a query` should read:

```
String SQLquery = "INSERT INTO one (Port,Name,Message) VALUES('a','hello','hii')";
```

Additionally:

- You have a line after this, `VALUES(1,'hello','muhsina')");`, which is just completely illegal syntax.  I'm guessing this was an accidental copy-paste error.
- You're using the query variable before you declare it, as others have pointed out.  You need to move the `st.executeUpdate()` call after the point where the query is declared.